# Can't get jqTree to load data from URL

Tags: jquery, json, jqtree

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but jqTree refuses to show up when I attempt to use dataUrl.

Looking in Chrome dev tools network tab, I can see that the js file is loaded, but even with the simplest bit of `JSON`, it won't build out a tree.

```
$('#tree1').tree({
    dataUrl: 'data.js'
});
```

Contents of `data.js`:

```
{
    label: 'node1',
    children: [
        { label: 'child1' },
        { label: 'child2' }
    ]
},
{
    label: 'node2',
    children: [
        { label: 'child3' }
    ]
 }
```

Any suggestions?  Is there some formatting issue with my JSON that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

The data should be in an array. So it should be:

```
[
    {
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
]
```